# Prestashop webservice 404 response

Tags: python, prestashop

I have some issue with prestashop's webservice. I'm trying to write a connection between prestashop and storage software. I simply use:

```
res = requests.request('GET', 'http://example.com/api', auth=('MY_KEY', ''))
print(res)
```

It's working well on other website but for current project not.I have 404 response. I think it is some problem with domain configuration. I looked for solutions but I wasn't find any. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

It may be because URL rewrite does not work on this website or Webservice isn't activated in shop's backoffice !

Comment: Everything is ok in backoffice.